# Dynamic ng-model into ng-repeat AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamically-generated, angularjs-ng-model

I'm trying to generate dynamically `ng-model` directive in `ng-repeat` but I receive an error from browser. We get dynamically attributes of a type and I would like to set its in DOM.

I'm recieving this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{'attribute.'+attribute.label}}] starting at [{'attribute.'+attribute.label}}].
```

Click [here](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=%E2%80%A6ibute.'%2Battribute.label%7D%7D&p4=%7B'attribute.'%2Battribute.label%7D%7D)

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attribute in objectType.objectAttributes | orderBy : attribute.order">
     <div class="col-sm-10" ng-if="attribute.multivalued==false">
          <input type="{{attribute.type}}" class="form-control"
              ng-model="{{'attribute.'+attribute.label}}">
     </div>
</div>
```

Do you have any idea which can help me to solve this problem? 
Thank you!

Comment: has nothing to do with angular... as in all javascript use `[]` notation for variable properties

Comment: it's not exactly clear why you need to do this in the first place, but your syntax is completely wrong.  you should be using bracket notation to access the dynamic properties, rather than dot notation.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't correct form and an error occurs if I tried but finally I did this and then I get the whole list of attributes. If change the input then change attribute.value into each attribute.
It 's very tricky but works!
Thank you!

```
<div ng-repeat="attribute in indoor.values | orderBy : attributes[$index].order">
     <input type="{{attributes[$index].type}}" class="form-control"
          ng-model="attribute.value">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way :

```
ng-model="attribute.{{attribute.label}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use {{}} in ng-model. Use [] for dynamic ng-model. In your case use like this

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="attribute in objectType.objectAttributes | orderBy : attribute.order">
 <div class="col-sm-10" ng-if="attribute.multivalued==false">
      <input type="{{attribute.type}}" class="form-control"
          ng-model="value1[attribute.label]">
 </div>
```

where "value1" in ng-model is your input value. But remember use $scope.value = [] in your controller. I hope it helps you